# (mongoose/promises) How do you check if document was created using findOneAndUpdate with upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, mongodb-query

Consider this code, where I need to either create or update a particular document.

```
Inbox.model.findOneAndUpdate({ number: req.phone.number }, {
    number: req.phone.number,
    country: req.phone.country,
    token: hat(),
    appInstalled: true
}, { new: true, upsert: true }).then(function(inbox){
    /*
       do something here with inbox, but only if the inbox was created (not updated)
    */
});
```

Does mongoose have a facility to be able to make the distinction between whether or not the documented was created or updated? I require `new: true` because I need to call functions on the `inbox`.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) or any of the `.findAndModify()` core driver variants for mongoose, the actual callback signature has "three" arguments:

```
 function(err,result,raw)
```

With the first being any error response, then the modified or original document depending on options and the third which is a write result of the issued statement.

That third argument should return data much like this:

```
{ lastErrorObject:
   { updatedExisting: false,
     n: 1,
     upserted: 55e12c65f6044f57c8e09a46 },
  value: { _id: 55e12c65f6044f57c8e09a46, 
           number: 55555555, 
           country: 'US', 
           token: "XXX", 
           appInstalled: true,
           __v: 0 },
  ok: 1 }
```

With the consistent field in there as `lastErrorObject.updatedExisting` being either `true/false` depending on the result of whether an upsert occured. Note that there is also a "upserted" value containing the `_id` response for the new document when this property is `false`, but not when it is `true`.

As such you would then modify your handling to consider the third condition, but this only works with a callback and not a promise:

```
Inbox.model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "number": req.phone.number },
    { 
      "$set": {
          "country": req.phone.country,
          "token": hat(),
          "appInstalled": true
      }
    }, 
    { "new": true, "upsert": true },
    function(err,doc,raw) {

      if ( !raw.lastErrorObject.updatedExitsing ) {
         // do things with the new document created
      }
    }
);
```

Where I would also strongly suggest you use [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) rather than raw objects here, as a raw object will always overwrite the entire document, yet operators like [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) just affect the listed fields.

Also noting that any matching "query arguments" to the statement are automatically assigned in the new document as long as their value is an exact match that was not found.

Given that using a promise does not seem to return the additional information for some reason, then do not see how this is possible with a promise other than setting `{ new: false}` and basically when no document is returned then it's a new one.

You have all the document data expected to be inserted anyway, so it is not like you really need that data returned anyway. It is in fact how the native driver methods handle this at the core, and only respond with the "upserted" `_id` value when an upsert occurs.

This really comes down to another issue discussed on this site, under:

[Can promises have multiple arguments to onFulfilled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22773920/5031275)

Where this really comes down to the resolution of multiple objects in a promise response, which is something not directly supported in the native speicification but there are approaches listed there.

So if you implement Bluebird promises and use the `.spread()` method there, then everything is fine:

```
var async = require('async'),
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test',testSchema,'test');
Promise.promisifyAll(Test);
Promise.promisifyAll(Test.prototype);

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      var promise = Test.findOneAndUpdateAsync(
        { "name": "Bill" },
        { "$set": { "name": "Bill" } },
        { "new": true, "upsert": true }
      );

      promise.spread(function(doc,raw) {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(raw);
        if ( !raw.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting ) {
          console.log( "new document" );
        }
        callback();
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which of course returns both objects and you can access then consistently:

```
{ _id: 55e14b7af6044f57c8e09a4e, name: 'Bill', __v: 0 }
{ lastErrorObject:
   { updatedExisting: false,
     n: 1,
     upserted: 55e14b7af6044f57c8e09a4e },
  value: { _id: 55e14b7af6044f57c8e09a4e, name: 'Bill', __v: 0 },
  ok: 1 }
```

Here is a full listing demonstrating the normal behaviour:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test',testSchema,'test');

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "name": "Bill" },
        { "$set": { "name": "Bill" } },
        { "new": true, "upsert": true }
      ).then(function(doc,raw) {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(raw);
        if ( !raw.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting ) {
          console.log( "new document" );
        }
        callback();
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

For the record, the native driver itself does not have this issue as the response object is in fact it's only object returned aside from any error:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  var collection = db.collection('test');

  collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "name": "Bill" },
    { "$set": { "name": "Bill" } },
    { "upsert": true, "returnOriginal": false }
  ).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

So it is always something like this:

```
{ lastErrorObject:
   { updatedExisting: false,
     n: 1,
     upserted: 55e13bcbf6044f57c8e09a4b },
  value: { _id: 55e13bcbf6044f57c8e09a4b, name: 'Bill' },
  ok: 1 }
```

Comment: I have tried looking at `raw` and it seems in the latest version to no longer exist (always is undefined). I am also using promises, which only provide a single argument to the `then(function(item)...`

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by creating my own `createOrUpdate` static.

Comment: @MattWay This is a bit suspect. Works fine with a plain callback, seems to be something about how things are being passed as a promise. Think I'll spend a few minutes looking at what is going wrong here.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2931 findAndModify only provides the doc (not raw).

Comment: @MattWay  That statement on the issue is not entrely true. I've added some information about what the native driver methods actually do, and also cleared this up with a working example. The issue here is the promise and not the functionality of the driver methods.

Comment: Any ideas why when I try with a callback instead of a promise, `raw` is always `undefined`?

Comment: @MattWay Trying to do some digging, but the clear thing right now seems to be that the promise is only ever getting the document response returned and no other arguments. If I find something concrete I'll add it.

Comment: @MattWay Something concrete with a bit more information.

Comment: If I understand correctly ... `promisifyAll()` is very expensive if you just want bluebird's `.spread()` method. After all `.spread()` does nothing that you can't do with `.then()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The point is the the "callback signature" that is required returns "two" useful arguments other than the "error" reponse. So the "success" is not a single object in the desired response where the detail required comes from the "second" object response. This is not supported by `.then()`. Hence you need to in "some way" define it so that `.spread()` is available to accept both responses. Ideally this would be ES6 and you would just cast the return value. So incorrect. In this case `.spread()` does something you cannot do with `.then()`

Comment: Ah OK, it's a bit confusing because the code in the question indicates that `.findOneAndUpdate()` is already thenable. If that's so then it would appear that it's own `.then()` callback is inadequate (exposes just doc), while it's direct callback is fully featured (exposes both doc and raw)?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Of course you "can" call then, but that is not the point. The point is the core method `.findOneAndUpdate()` can possibly return `(err,doc,raw)` but when you call with `.then()` you only get `doc` which is why you call `.spread()` so you can get `(doc,raw)` which you cannot get with `.then()` as there are "two" arguments. `.then()` is a "higlander". I already have links in here that explain this as well as the examples.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thats ["highlander"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=highlander+there+can+be+only+one)

Answer (score 1):

For people using this with Promises, According to [this link from Mongoosejs.com](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) we can pass `rawResult: true` along with other options.

```
const filter = { name: 'Will Riker' };
const update = { age: 29 };

await Character.countDocuments(filter); // 0

let res = await Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
  rawResult: true // Return the raw result from the MongoDB driver
});

res.value instanceof Character; // true
// The below property will be `false` if MongoDB upserted a new
// document, and `true` if MongoDB updated an existing object.
res.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting; /
```

and the result from this query will be of the format

```
{ lastErrorObject:
   { n: 1,
     updatedExisting: false,
     upserted: 5e6a9e5ec6e44398ae2ac16a },
  value:
   { _id: 5e6a9e5ec6e44398ae2ac16a,
     name: 'Will Riker',
     __v: 0,
     age: 29 },
  ok: 1 }
```

so the document can be accessed at `data.value`